# Multiple Buttons start multiple Activities at once

Tags: android, button, onclick, android-activity

Im coding a little Android-App at the moment and discovered a strange issue regarding multiple Buttons. I have an Activity with 4 Buttons on it. When I press multiple Buttons at once, both actions are executed. So I can press all 4 Buttons and all 4 following Activities are started.

This is my onButtonClick-Method

```
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RunActivityConfirm.class);

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnRunAcceleration:
            intent.putExtra("DisciplineName", "Acceleration");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.btnRunSkidPad:
            intent.putExtra("DisciplineName", "Skid Pad");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.btnRunAutocross:
            intent.putExtra("DisciplineName", "Autocross");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.btnRunEndurance:
            intent.putExtra("DisciplineName", "Endurance");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }

}
```

First I thought the problem ist that I always call startActivity()  in every single "case" but even if I try the following all 4 Activities get started at the same time

```
public void onButtonClick(View view){   
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RunActivityConfirm.class);

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnRunAcceleration:
            intent.putExtra("DisciplineName", "Acceleration");
            break;
        case R.id.btnRunSkidPad:
            intent.putExtra("DisciplineName", "Skid Pad");
            break;
        case R.id.btnRunAutocross:
            intent.putExtra("DisciplineName", "Autocross");
            break;
        case R.id.btnRunEndurance:
            intent.putExtra("DisciplineName", "Endurance");
            break;
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This happens all over my App. No matter which Button I press every associated Action is executed and every associated Activity is started.

Is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I press multiple Buttons at once, both actions are executed.

This is expected behavior. Your code starts an activity when a button is pressed. Multiple buttons are pressed, so multiple activities are started.

If you want to change this so that only one button can be pressed, then you need to add code to do so. You could disable the other buttons in `onButtonClick` (and re-enable them when appropriate).

Comment: OK what a strange behaviour. Is there really no other solution? I can activate everything at once on every activity in my app (e.g. Menu and all Buttons) in other Apps that's not possible. Seems a little bit time-consuming to me.

Comment: @Willey : "OK what a strange behaviour." - Why is it strange behaviour? Assuming this is a multi-touch screen then why is it strange that multiple events are generated when multiple UI elements are touched? "...in other Apps that's not possible." - Probably because the authors of other apps you've tried disable other UI elements when the first is touched/clicked or they ignore anything but the first event.

Comment: I think it's a strange behaviour because I don't see the advantages of it. I pressed the two buttons together accidentally and both actions were executed without me noticing it. Let's say I want wo write something important and press the delete-button at the same time the information is lost and I never notice it. That's a serious problem for me. In addition to that I dont see why a "normal" app should respond to multiple inputs at the same time as long it isn't a multitouch-game.

Comment: Every App I know is used with one finger (aside from zooming) so 2 finger clicks are most of the time made by accident. So for me it would be more natural if the normal case would be single-touch and only if you really need multitouch you can activate it separately. I hope I could make my point. English isn't my native language ;)

Comment: @Willey : Yes, I understand your point. I think you need to think differently from using a mouse on a computer screen. With a mouse it is impossible to click two buttons at the same time but with a touch screen it is different. In a touch screen environment a 'click' on a `Button` is just a 'touch event' like any other touch on the screen. You need to plan the design of the UI and the event handling to make sure that a false (accidental) touch won't cause a problem. Yes, it requires extra effort to write code to do this but it is as a result of the complexity of touch screens.

Answer (score 0):

As this is the same Activity add

```
android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
```

in your manifest under your activity tag.It will prevent to make the multiple instances of same activity.